# Execution Plan shows a sort - but can't figure a way around because of query

Tags: sql, sorting, execution

Here is my query -- the last query is what is causing me pain:
The address.postcode field is a varchar(14) and you can see the input format the user sends in.

```
DECLARE @ZipCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = ('06409;06471;11763;06443;06371;11949;11946;11742')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ZipCodes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ZipCodes;

CREATE TABLE #ZipCodes (
Zipcode NVARCHAR(6)
)

INSERT INTO #ZipCodes ( Zipcode )
SELECT zip.Token + '%'
FROM DMS.fn_SplitList(@ZipCode, ';')  zip

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Zip] ON #ZipCodes (Zipcode)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ZipCodesConstituents') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ZipCodesConstituents;

CREATE TABLE #ZipCodesConstituents (
ConstituentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
, PostCode NVARCHAR(12)
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_ZipCodesConstituents] ON #ZipCodesConstituents (ConstituentID, PostCode)

INSERT INTO #ZipCodesConstituents ( ConstituentID, PostCode )
SELECT a.CONSTITUENTID
, a.POSTCODE
FROM #ZipCodes zip
JOIN DMS.address  a  
    ON a.POSTCODE LIKE zip.Zipcode  
where a.ISPRIMARY = 1
```

I am trying to attach the execution plan -- but not having any luck...
Basically the section of code has an Est Cost of 61.9%
and the Sort is 61.5%

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'd like to improve the performance and the Sort is causing the glut. Would like any ideas on how I can get rid of the Sort or another way to optimize.

Comment: Why are you creating the index before you insert? I don't know about the sort without the execution plan, but having the index will slow down every insert because the system has to update the index for every row inserted. That may actually be whats causing the sort, as sql looks for a way to minimize the impact of the index.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. Sort gone. Thank you @Randall Matthews!

Comment: Oh, but now I'm back to an original issue I had with a huge index scan of the DMS.ADDRESS table and pulling 150,485,448 rows but the table insert is only 10,313 rows. For some reason adding that index early kept that from happening ....Basically the plan shows an Index scan on #ZipCodes using the index idx_zip -- and Index scan on ADDRESS using an index but pulling all the rows in address -- then a nested loop inner join and then insert into the table #ZipCodesConstituents  --- Any ideas to get rid of my FAT arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to evaluate the behavior, but on my tests, I can't force a sort operator in the last `INSERT`. But what I see are the following two issues.

1. You create the index, and afterwards insert into the table. This *may* be harmful. Not in all cases, but it may force the sort in your query, as SQL Server tries to ensure the right order during the insert to help the index at its reorganize.
2. Your using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` as your primary keys. This may be useful in a way, but I think in your case a simple `IDENTITY(1,1)` column would be enough, doesn't it? The `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in your index, will heavily force a fragmentation. It might not be the best idea to solve it this way.

I tested both variants with a test-set of 100.000 rows.
These are my results in measurement of the execution costs:

- In all cases, the costs are significantly lower, if the Index is created **after** the `INSERT` of `#ZipCodesConstituents`.
- The usage of an `INDENTITY` instead of an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` will additionally boost the performance.
- It would be wise to add a Index on your Address table, if your running this sort of query more often.

Here are the measurements in cost-points (cp) - the lower the better:

- `UniqueIdentifier` + Index before: 20 cp for the `Insert`.
- `UniqueIdentifier` + Index after Insert: 8 cp for the `Insert` + 7 for the Index (where the `SORT` occurs).
- `Identity` + Index before: 18 cp for the `Insert`
- `Identity` + Index after: 7 cp for the `Insert` + 6 for the Index
- `Identity` + Index after + Index on `Address`: 3 for the `Insert` + 6 for the Index

And the winner is: `Identity` Column + Index and maybe an Index on your `Address` too.

The index I used to boost both of the statements (`UniqueIdentifier` and `Identity`) is this one:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_Adress_IsPrimary_Postcode]
ON Address ([IsPrimary],[PostCode])
INCLUDE ([Constituentid])
```

In my testcase it took 13 cp to build it. If you just use this once, it won't be helpful! If you use this statement quite often or even sometimes a day/week it may be useful for you.

Hopefully this will solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks @Ionic. I have to keep the uniqueidentifier to join back to another table, but I think with putting the index after the insert and adding the Address table index, I will get the best performance I can expect -- since I have to keep the uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Yes, the difference between `identity` and `uniqueidentifier` is marginal in this use-case.